# c# mvc razor view foreach create dynamic table columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model with 4 properties and each property is a `List<T>`

Now I want to build a table and the data from each of the 4 propeties will be shown in it's own column. The properties can have different amount of items in them.

[image]

How can I loop through the properties of my model and show their items in their own column?

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public class List<Custom1> Prop1 {get; set;}
   public class List<Custom2> Prop2 {get; set;}
   public class List<Custom3> Prop3 {get; set;}
   public class List<Custom4> Prop4 {get; set;}
}

Custom1, Custom2, Custom3, Custom4 are all POCO clases and have one common property called Name.
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without seeing your model.

Comment: @Jasen: updated question

Comment: Find the max length (M) among the properties. Then use a _for_ loop to iterate M times. Access using the indexer `model.Prop1[i]`. You'll need to check to make sure you don't go out-of-bounds since each collection is a different size.

Comment: A different display layout would be easier and you could foreach each property. `row0: Prop1 - Item1  Item2 | row1: Prop2 - Item1  Item2  Item3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the max length (M) among the properties. Then use a for loop to iterate M times. Access using the indexer `model.Prop1[i]`. You'll need to check to make sure you don't go out-of-bounds since each collection is a different size.

```
@{
    int rowCount = GetMax(model.Prop1, model.Prop2, model.Prop3);
    int p1Size = model.Prop1.Count();
    int p2Size = model.Prop2.Count();
    int p3Size = model.Prop3.Count();
}

@for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    var c1 = (i < p1Size) ? model.Prop1[i] : "";
    var c2 = (i < p2Size) ? model.Prop2[i] : "";
    var c3 = (i < p3Size) ? model.Prop3[i] : "";

    <tr><td>@c1</td><td>@c2</td><td>@c3</td></tr>
}
```